# Jenkins only shows artefacts and test results for current directory

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins and not sure that I phrased the question correctly so let me show the example of the problem.

I have a step that runs an sh command which starts python script with Unit tests.
I am working on Linux and like to use this script manually too so I hardcoded the path for JUnit report.
Jenkins runs its builds in docker environment with the same Linux as mine (or pretty much the same)

This is how I am running the script

```
stage("test")
{
  dir('root')
  {
     sh 'python3 Test.py' 
  }
}
```

Now I want to get test results and save them:

```
stage("test")
 {
      dir('root')
      {
         sh 'python3 Test.py' 
      }
       junit allowEmptyResults: false, keepLongStdio: true, testResults: '/tmp/results.xml' 

       archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: false, artifacts:  '/tmp/results.xml'  

 }
```

My script successfully saved its results to this path, and Jenkins wrote in console 'Recording test results' but didn't show any tests results so far.

The only way I've made it work is like this:

```
stage("test")
 {
      dir('root')
      {
         sh 'python3 Test.py'
         sh 'cp /tmp/results.xml Results/results.xml'

         junit allowEmptyResults: false, keepLongStdio: true, testResults: '**/Results/results.xml' 

         archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: false, artifacts:  '**/Results/results.xml'   

      }

 }
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's much safer for your unit test program to write results into the current directory. Using a single location invites problems with multiple test instances overwriting each other. It seems like Jenkins is encouraging you to the right thing -- don't fight it.

Comment: @DaveBacher ,well, that's a good point really, I maybe change this behavior because pipeline code really looks clumsy. But I am still not sure why Jenkins commands works like this. Just in my view, Jenkins should "see" all default Linux directories.